# Could not update \.gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes\last-build.bin

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

i am new to Jenkins and trying to setup build automation and testing but whenever i run my build it fails by giving me following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update C:\Users\Embrace-IT\.gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes\last-build.bin
> C:\Users\Embrace-IT\.gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)
```

Answer (score 7):

Go to the dir C:\Users\Embrace-IT.gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes\ and check the properties of file "last-build.bin". If it is hidden, then make it unhidden and also you can check the permissions of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vishal Chaudhary :)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed to me:
Delete "**last-build.bin**" file in path "**C:\Users\username\ .gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes**", if you have a new project. *I don't know if affect old files yet*.

Others Versions:
Delete "**last-build.bin**" file in path "**C:\Users\username\ .gradle\caches\x.x\file-changes**", if you have a new project. *I don't know if affect old files yet*.

`I had see more forums and i did not find solution to this.`

I hope so help you.

> Yander Sanchez

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

```
git rm -r --cached .idea/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply goto to C:\Users\Embrace-IT.gradle\caches\4.4\file-changes\
2. open the properties window for last-build.bin
3. Make sure it's not hidden

It'll definitely work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error:
"Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.\r\nCould not update C:\Users\92342\.gradle\caches\7.5\file-changes\last-build.bin\r\nC:\Users\92342\.gradle\caches\7.5\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)""

I simply search this file "C:\Users\92342\.gradle\caches\7.5\file-changes\last-build.bin" and deleted that file that work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).